# gcm works on emulator but give canonical_ids":0 in my device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When I send a push notification to the emulator I get this message:

```
{"multicast_id":8595716062607030073,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":1,"results":            [{"message_id":"0:1403002114354553%44f16b55f9fd7ecd","registration_id":"XXXXXXX...
```

But after registering and sending the notification to my device with the new regId i get this :

```
{"multicast_id":8356469968000736599,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1403002260325568%44f16b55f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

I activated the notification in my phone and connected with Google account
Also i get the new registration ID in my database when registering but i cant figure out the problem 
Here is my manifest.xml:

```
   <!-- for gcm -->
    <receiver                        
        android:name="com.test.android.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.test.android.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.test.android.gcm.GCMNotificationIntentService" />
    <!-- end for gcm -->
    <!-- GCM activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.android.gcm.RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.test.android.gcm.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <!-- End GCM activity -->
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction please

Comment: Your question in not clear. Are you using an emulator or a device? Did you ever see a notification on the device/emulator? If not, please post your code (GCMNotificationIntentService, GcmBroadcastReceiver and full manifest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it works.

When registering a client to GCM you get a registration ID. Let's call it ***A***. Your server will hold on to that for it to be able to send notifications.

Time goes by and for whatever reason, say expiration of the registration ID in the GCM server, GCM decides to give the same client a different, newer ID. We'll call it ***B***. Your server holds on to that one, too.

Now you have to IDs for the same device, one is old and another is up to date. They will ***both be valid for sending notifications***.

In a MulticastResult, receiving a Canonical ID means that the ID you're using isn't the most recent ID. When you do receive a canonical ID, it should replace the one you're using (since it's the most up to date ID).

For ***A*** you'll receive a MulticastResult with success=1, canonical id=***B***. For ***B*** you'll just receive success=1 because it is the most recent ID. The response for ***A*** indicates it is out of date and should be replace by ***B***.

Since in your case you're using a newly registered ID (like you've said), there's no reason for it to be out of date, and there is no problem with your code.

***As for why you are not getting the notification,*** your client has to have a receiver class that extends [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html), and handles the incoming notification:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

and an `IntentService` to complete the picture

`public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

```
public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
         * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
         * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
         * recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                    extras.toString());
        // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // This loop represents the service doing some work.
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                        + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            // Post notification of received message.
            sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

// Put the message into a notification and post it.
// This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
// a GCM message.
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
    .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

See [Implementing a GCM client](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html).

Comment: Sorry but i am new with GCM so i didn't understand exactly your answer(when you talk about ID you mean registration ID ?), can you tell me what exactly i can do to resolve this or where my proble is

Comment: First, there is no problem. This behavior is expected.

Comment: Second, I've update my answer. Don't forget to accept it if it helps you. :)

Comment: It did help me undrestand the process but still i dont get the notifications in my device

Comment: That is an entirely different issue. You need a class that extends `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` in your client. See http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html. Please accept the answer as it answers your question completely.

Comment: @EranGoldin This might answer the question as it was phrased before it was edited, but it doesn't answer the current question - why the OP doesn't get the notification on his device.

Comment: @Eran that is a good point. Updated the answer to include that information as well.